# Why does an 'idle' process not generate (much) heat?

Tags: cpu

As I understand it, a running CPU can never actually be doing nothing. Even if there is no active 'job' being run, there will always be an 'idle process' running, to keep the CPU 'ticking over'.

So, my question is: why does this idle process not generate much heat, like other processes do? Why are all CPUs/GPUs not always at their maximum running temperature (once they've started up)?

Comment: It's simple. Less transistors are actually used and the CPU can run at lower power states.

Comment: @JaroslavKucera I guess I was hoping for something a little deeper than 'it uses less transistors'. Can you explain more about these power states and why the idle process is able to run in a lower power state than other processes?

Comment: I find this to be an interesting topic. Take a look at here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idle_(CPU) as it discusses a few options. It seems it really depends on the processor in question as well as OS

Answer (score 3):

The idle process uses a halt instruction, which most CPUs have for precisely this purpose.

When halted the CPU does not run, but waits for an interrupt which will start it running again.

On Intel processors, [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT_(x86_instruction)) details the `HLT` instruction.

Comment: So, when the system is 'idle', the CPU (which has a halt instruction) is actually *not* running - it is in some sort of suspended state? So, my statement that a CPU always has to be running something was false?

Comment: I know this is true for Windows but is it true for other OS's like Linux and the MacOS? Does AMD do this as well? A good answer, just some other pieces that should be answered I think

Comment: @EricF - Since it's happening on the on the questioner's OS, this is almost certainly the explanation. I believe early Windows (9x) did not use it (I recall a looping application which did it instead), but it has been true in WinNT and its progeny. I am pretty sure it's true of Linux, and therefore of MacOS, which is Linux-based.

Comment: @Time4Tea - Yes. I would probably define the CPU as active, but not running.

Answer (score 1):

Current CPUs/GPUs are (still) build upon [CMOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS). A significant part of the power consumption in CMOS circuits is caused by digital signals changing their values ("dynamic" power consumption).

The "idle process" tries to reduce signal changes as much as possible, i.e. by continuously executing the same instruction - typically called the no-operation (NOP). As a result, the CPU/GPU consumes less power.

Furthermore, the CPU/GPU detects that it is actually doing "very little" if only NOP instructions are to be executed. Thus, CPU clock is throttled and for parts of the CPU/GPU, the clock signal can even be turned off ("clock gating") and/or the supply voltage of these parts can be lowered or can even be reduced to 0.

The latter measure also reduces the "static" power consumption ("leakage") of CMOS circuits, which increases with smaller CMOS feature sizes and lower nominal supply voltage levels.

Comment: More precisely, as [AFH](https://superuser.com/users/327367/afh) points out in an earlier answer, not the NOP but the HLT (halt) instruction is executed during the idle process.